# @ViewChild using classname and ID not working when trying to appendChild

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying add a button to div with specific class

Here is my ViewChild initiated

```
  @ViewChild('.ttest', { static: true }) toolbarElement!: ElementRef;
```

and in my AfterViewInit

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const button = this.renderer.createElement('button');
    const buttonText = this.renderer.createText('Email Reports');
    
    this.renderer.appendChild(button, buttonText);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.toolbarElement.nativeElement, button);
  }
```

But its not seems to creating button inside my div with class **ttest**

But instead of class name if I specify my div like this

```
<div class='col' #ttest>..</div>
```

and on changing the view child into this

```
@ViewChild('ttest', { static: true }) toolbarElement!: ElementRef;
```

its working fine and a button getting created

Also when creating div like

```
 <div class='col' id='ttest'>...</div>
 @ViewChild('ttest', { static: true }) toolbarElement!: ElementRef;
```

its not working (like class)

So only situation its working is #ttest as attribute

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: `@ViewChild()` support a template reference variable or the name of the class of a component/directive. I think you're confused with directive, that allow more selectors (like a class, or html element or...). Well, always can create a directive with the selector you want and in constructor inject the ElementRef as public: `constructor(public element:ElementRef){}`, and use the name of the directive to use the ViewChild

Answer (score 7):

If you check the documentation here for the supported selectors in `@ViewChild()` here: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description, you can see that you need to pass a template reference variable.

`class` or `id` are not supported as selector!